# how do i see python execution in django html?

Tags: python, html, django, include

i have a script for putting values into a table that takes values from the db with python in the html include file in django, but it isnt taking the values from the db. how do i stop the execution and check the current values at runtime?
note; the code is indented properly, just when i pasted it here it lost the indent.

```
${self.target_month_year(year, month, this_year, this_month)}
    <table class="table table-bordered" style="width:auto" id="csv">
        <thead>
            <th>Rate</th>
             % if states:
                 % for k in states:
                     <th>${k}</th>
                % endfor
             % else:
                 <th></th>
             % endif
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of your last question.  You need to use a debugger to see values, Pycharm Pro lets you debug django templates as I'm sure other tools do too

Comment: If you are using Django, why are you writing in Mako syntax?

Comment: copy paste.. whats mako